# Standard sql subquery to ActiveRecord Relation, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-relation

I've got a piece of code where I have to applies some subqueries. I'm trying to change this piece of pure sql to more rails way. Is it possible to implement ActiveRecord Relation here?

```
Customer.joins("RIGHT JOIN customers_users ON customers_users.customer_id = customers.id").
         where("customers_users.user_id IN (
                                    SELECT user_id FROM customers_users
                                    GROUP BY customers_users.user_id
                                    HAVING COUNT(customers_users.user_id) = 1)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can convert it rails way like

first create a relation to customer_users in customer model

```
Customer.joins(:customers_users).where(customers_users: { user_id: CustomersUser.select(:user_id).group(:user_id).having('COUNT(customers_users.user_id) = 1') })
```